# How can I create a SDS Cross Point Drillbit?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I don´t know how to approximate to the creation of this object, maybe I have to use sculpting plus modeling in order to achieve this, it´s not as easy as making the form of the object and then using the screw modifier to make a spiral, I used other things like archimedean and helix forms and then manually adjusting, but I think there is an easier path for making this.

I need like an starting point, maybe another way to create this, a good starting point.

Thanks in advance

[image: Front]
[image: Side]

[image: Top View]

Comment: what part are you struggling with? You can certainly get the screw part with the Screw modifier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to approximate this object with high fidelity is that you use the twist option of the simple deform modifier and put it to 720 degrees, in the section of the simple deform modifier, then from that point, you can recreate the double flute. If you are using 3DSMax, there is a twist modifier as well.

Don't forget to flip normal and then extrude them to make the flutes, the cross it's a little bit tricky but then it will take form step by step.